# How to insert 3 elements or another odd number of elements in an unordered_map?

Tags: c++, c++11, unordered-map

I'm working on some sort of transit app, i have stations and i putting the connections between them in an unordered_map. A connection is : departure_station_id,arrival_station_id,travel_time.

As you can see, there are three elements. 
Here is what i have already tried.

```
uint64_t fr=strtoul(from.c_str(),NULL,10);
uint64_t t=strtoul(to.c_str(),NULL,10);
uint64_t tf_time=strtoul(tfr.c_str(),NULL,10);
connections_hashmap.insert({{fr,t},tf_time});
```

I obtain this :

```
 error: no matching function for call to ‘std::unordered_map<long unsigned int, std::unordered_map<long unsigned int, long unsigned int> >::insert(<brace-enclosed initializer list>)’                                                                     connections_hashmap.insert({{fr,t},tf_time});
```

I have tried also to form a {tf_time,NULL} pair, but i didn't work.

Comment: A map is pretty much the same as a dictionary. In a dictionary you give it a **word** and it gives you back a **definition**. Similarly, for a map, you give it a **key** and it gives you back a **value**. So if you're going to use a map here, you have to decide what the appropriate key is: what do you want to be able to look up. And you have to provide a single type for the value, typically a `struct` (or a `class`) that holds the various pieces that belong to the value.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]; at the minimum, the definition of `connections_hashmap`.

Answer (score 0):

You should define a connection as a struct, and then insert that under some meaningful ID:

```
struct connection {
  string departure_station_id;
  string arrival_station_id;
  string travel_time;
};

auto connections_hashmap = new unordered_map<string, connection>();
connections_hashmap.insert("connectionID", {"Powell", "Embarcadero", "3"});
```

This will let you retrieve the struct by connectionID later.

Comment: that's an interesting idea. Thanks. I was expecting there would be some sort of standard way to do it.

Comment: This is relatively standard in that you will see it in many/most code bases that include the same issue.  I am not aware of an off the shelf solution that allows you to store more than a Key:Value pair.  This is because unordered_map/hashtables/dictionaries by definition internally store Value at some index determined by a function of Key.  I would expect any solution with a third key to be very niche.